# Calculate the histogram h(x) from V component from HSV image

Tags: matlab, histogram

i'm wondering if it would be possible to  help me to find out how to implement this equation in  Matlab for Calculate the histogram h(x) from V
component from HSV image

```
X*h(x)/ h(x)
```

which X is intensity value and H(x) is the histogram result

Comment: This question is the definition of "too little information to even understand whats going on". What do you need? why doesnt literally that line you got work? what do you expect?

Comment: first of all i need to use imhist() function to draw Calculate Histogram then i must use the result of that function in this equation  ,so i do not know how i can save and obtain  the result of that function and also  obtaining intensity value to use them in this Equalization

Comment: have you tried `[count,midvalue]=imhist(image)`? Its in the docs: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html